# Filter-Interceptor-Kafka topics

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, apache-storm, spring-kafka

Hi am trying to build a analytical engine to determine realtime analysis of urls\events being used by client as well as to log the performance of api.

Following is the logic I am planning to implement:
1. Create a filter to intercept urls
2. Code filter as a reusable jar which have the logic to intercept them
using mvc-interceptors.
3. The interceptor will produce and publish events into kafka streams if url pattern is matched.

My confusion is this is the best approach to achieve this. Or is there any alternative better approach, keeping in mind high traffice flow into apis.

Comment: Sounds fine. The logic within the interceptors should be asynchronous in order to prevent it from interrupting the normal flow of your application

Answer (score 0):

If the filtering is just done a single message at a time it could also be done in Kafka Connect using the new Single Message Transforms feature https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-66%3A+Single+Message+Transforms+for+Kafka+Connect